# when I execute the code then I got java.lang.IllegalStateException:

Tags: javafx

I got error when execute code. I think it's not related to code. something is missing.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Problem in some module which uses Window System: Window System API is required to be called from AWT thread only, see http://core.netbeans.org/proposals/threading/
```

Answer (score 2):

You have flagged your post with JavaFX, so I assume you are talking about a JavaFX application. Every GUI update in the JavaFX-world is done on the JavaFX application thread. Your exception however indicates that you are using some AWT code in your program which has a different requirement. It must be run on AWT thread. So, the first thing you have to do is find out what this code is and then you have to make sure to call it on the right thread. You can use `Platform.runLater()` to put something on the JavaFX thread and `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` to put something on the AWT thread.